Cannot recover Marginal Distribution from Product Distribution
In this simple example MarginalDistribution is unable to recover the marginal distribution from a Product Distribution. Why does it fail?
Start with a simple empirical distribution (It is a discrete uniform distribution but could be any discrete distribution).
empdist = WeightedData[{1, 2, 3}, {1/3, 1/3, 1/3}]["EmpiricalDistribution"];

Construct a discrete distribution by mixing products of discrete uniform distribution and this empirical distribution. Mathematica nicely captures the PDF of this constructed distribution.
constructeddist =  MixtureDistribution[{1/2, 1/2}, 
                                      {ProductDistribution[DiscreteUniformDistribution[{1, 1}], 
                                                           empdist],
                                       ProductDistribution[DiscreteUniformDistribution[{2, 2}], 
                                                           empdist]}];

PDF[constructeddist, {x, y}] // InputForm
(* Output:  Piecewise[{{(Boole[1 == y]/3 + Boole[2 == y]/3 + Boole[3 == y]/3)/2, x^2 >= 0 && (x == 1 || x == 2)}}, 0] *)

Finally, derive a distribution from the constructed distribution. Again, Mathematica nicely captures the PDF of this derived distribution.
deriveddist = TruncatedDistribution[{0, \[Infinity]},  
                                   TransformedDistribution[y - 1, 
                                   y \[Distributed] MarginalDistribution[ 
                                                    TruncatedDistribution[{{0, 1}, None}, 
                                                                          constructeddist], 2]];
PDF[deriveddist,  y] // InputForm
(* Output: Piecewise[{{1/2, Inequality[0, Less, y, LessEqual, 2]}}, 0] *)

The trouble arises when we construct a product distribution using this derived distribution:
proddist = ProductDistribution[DiscreteUniformDistribution[{2, 2}],  deriveddist];

Mathematica simply returns the input in response to anything involving this proddist:
PDF[proddist, {x, y}]
(* Output: PDF[ProductDistribution[DiscreteUniformDistribution[{2, 2}], ... *)

Probability[{x == 2, y == 1}, {x, y} \[Distributed] proddist]
(* Output: 
Probability[{x == 2, y == 1}, {x, y} \[Distributed] ProductDistribution[DiscreteUniformDistribution[{2, 2}],... *)

NProbability[{x == 2, y == 1}, {x, y} \[Distributed] proddist]
(* Output: 
NProbability[{x == 2, y == 1}, {x, y} \[Distributed] ProductDistribution[DiscreteUniformDistribution[{2, 2}],... *)

Most concerning is that MarginalDistribution is unable to recover the derived distribution:
marginaldist = MarginalDistribution[proddist, 2];
PDF[marginaldist, y]
(* Output: PDF[MarginalDistribution[
  ProductDistribution[DiscreteUniformDistribution[{2, 2}],... *)

Probability[y <= 2, y \[Distributed] marginaldist]
(* Output: Probability[y <= 2, 
 y \[Distributed] MarginalDistribution[ProductDistribution[...*)

It does recover the discrete uniform distribution as the first marginal distribution.
MarginalDistribution[proddist,1]
(* Output: DiscreteUniformDistribution[{2, 2}] *)

Strangely, reconstructing the derived distribution from its PDF resolves these issues:
deriveddist2 = ProbabilityDistribution[PDF[deriveddist, y], {y, 0, \[Infinity], 1}];
proddist2 = ProductDistribution[DiscreteUniformDistribution[{2,2}], deriveddist2];
PDF[proddist2, {x, y}]//InputForm
(* Output: Piecewise[{{1/2, x^2 >= 0 && Inequality[0, Less, y, LessEqual, 2] && x == 2}}, 0] *)

Is the issue that somehow deriveddist is interpreted as a continuous distribution? Is there a mechanism to prevent this?  Suggestions how to proceed? What am I missing?

Looks like a bug to me, I will need to investigate...
